# Are there more numbers in this sequence?

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, factoring

Are more numbers in this sequence that starts with $2$,$4$,...?

A number is in this sequence if all its factors add up to the same number as the product of the prime of its digits.

so 2 is in this list because $1$+$2$=prime($2$), and $4$ is in this list because  $1+2+4$ =Prime($4$)

12 isn't in this sequence because $1+2+3+4+6+12$ is not $=$ to prime($1$)$\times$prime($2$)

** for 10 we would have Prime(1) we ignore 0
so 120 would be prime(1)$\times$prime(2)

all I want to know is there more in this sequence and is there infinity more?

Comment: Why the fascination with sums of factors?  You asked a related question yesterday.

Comment: What is prime(0) in this context?  To confirm, you are as with last time excluding the number itself as a factor, yes?

Comment: @JMoravitz good point I'll edit the question thanks for telling me the problem I meant to add that

Comment: @JMoravitz I like doing random stuff with factors look for patterns. they fantastic to learn about.

Comment: What on earth is the "prime of a number"? why is $prime(2)=3$ and $prime(4) =7$

Comment: $3$ is the second prime, $7$ is the fourth prime.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no more.  Note that since the $9$'th prime is $23$, the sum of primes of the digits of an $n$-digit number is at most $23n$.  But the sum of factors of an $n$-digit number is at least $10^{n-1}$ (since the number itself is a factor).  For $n \ge 3$,
$10^{n-1} > 23 n$, so there can't be any terms with $3$ or more digits.  And by
a search we find the only ones with $1$ or $2$ digits are $2$ and $4$.

You might do better if you used the product rather than sum of primes of the digits: $2, 4, 148, 484$ would work (and I don't know if there are more; that's all up to $10^6$).

Comment: "*since the number itself is a factor*"  Not to the OP.  Or... at least it wasn't the last the the OP asked a question like this.

Comment: @JMoravitz Yes it is, see the cases of 2 and 4.

Comment: oh I said sum I meant product but you're right tho I'll fix that